# distributed across the nodes if we are using loop approach in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

1. the data is pused into master node if we are using collect() and it will not distributed the data across
   the nodes.
2. if we implemented the multithreading concept inside the loop, parllel processing will not happen across the nodes
   still it will run in same master node

df_lists=df.collect()
for i in df_lists:
<<logic operations)

is there any way to distributed across the nodes if we are using loop concept in **pyspark** with/without multithreading

Comment: Could you share the reason why you want to loop through the dataframe using a for loop?

Comment: we have to implement the row pattern recognition (similar to match_recognize in snowflake or oracle) which means that comparing the current row and previous row. the previous row is changing based on the condition. we cannot directly implement the using lead and lag functions..so we tried to use loop using collect() to implement the row pattern recognition logic